# uploaded documents not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode, urldecode

```
<?php if($row->resumes != null){
         $attachment= base_url().'uploads/resumes/'.$row->resumes;
         echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$attachment.'">
          Show Resume</a>';
      }
?>
```

Suppose, my file name is, `my plan.pdf`

so, on click of `Show Resume` then in url it's open like,
`../uploads/resumes/my%20plan.pdf`
in my resumes folder is store like `my plan.pdf`
there for `404 Page Not Found` error is coming

i tried to using urlencode & urldecode, but  it's not working.

Comment: replace or delete spaces(or more specsymbols) from name on upload

Comment: Make sure the file is actually there as well

Comment: @ReenaShirale, I can not read your thoughts and code remotely, but means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @maximkou, it works. using your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it might be the problem of white-space.
You may use `trim()` while inserting and retrieving time. or read  [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/trim)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because of the space in the filename.  I suggest that you use the Codeigniter [upload class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) if you aren't already and remove any spaces from the file name before uploading.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';
$config['file_name'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $filename); //Remove all whitespace

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Once the file has been uploaded you can get the name of the file by doing

```
$aUploadData = $this->upload->data();
$aUploadData['file_name'];
```

Then **once you have that** value you should insert it into your database because that way you will know that the value stored in the database will match the name of the file uploaded

Also as an extra check you should check to see if the file exists before linking to it

```
<?php if($row->resumes != null) {
    if(file_exists(base_url().'uploads/resumes/'.$row->resumes)) {
        $attachment= base_url().'uploads/resumes/'.$row->resumes;
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$attachment.'">Show Resume</a>';
    }
}
```

?>

Hope that helps